# External access to file shelf

Tags: google-chrome-os

I am testing a Google Chrome notebook. Whenever I download a file it goes to a folder called "File shelf" which is somehow connected to my Gmail account.  Is it possible to access this folder on a "normal" system running any browser?  I did not find how to do it yet. In general, is there a description on how to manage this folder: delete, copy to external storage (USB), etc?

Answer (score 0):

The 'File shelf' is not connected to your Gmail. It's a place on the SSD. If you click 'Ctrl-M' you will get a folder with all the files on your local SSD.

Once you are in the folder - right click will give you the options to delete/rename each file.
If you want wish to do more with this new File API - here is a [post](http://greenido.wordpress.com/2011/06/10/how-to-use-the-new-chromebook-file-api/) I've wrote on it.
Good luck.

Comment: You're right: 'File shelf' resides in local SSD, but I should have asked a different question.  I wanted a simple way to be used by a complete lay person (after all that's the idea of a Chrome OS user) to upload a file (say .doc) I downloaded from the Internet to be processed by my Gmail "Documents".  When I select it in the file manager it does not show the upload option; however if I enter my Gmail Documents I can use its "upload" option to perform the operation. It would be nice if an option "Send to Documents" similar to "Send to Picasa" appeared when I select the downloaded file.

Comment: This ext will do it for you: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/geojifjnplelmefbggiioamokdomjenf